# Embed flash stream for android web browser

Tags: android, flash, browser, mobile, embed

I have been scratching my head for several days over this issue. I am attempting to embed a flash stream from own3d.tv in a HTML page that is view-able in the android web browser. No matter what I do the flash object goes white several seconds after the page loads. I have tried copying their exact code as well as using swfobject but have had no luck. The more confusing part is I am able to view the same stream on their homepage just fine. (own3d.tv). Here are the details:

**What I am using:**

- Android 4.0.1 on Google Galaxy Nexus
- swfobject 2.0
- Flash 11
- Always use a stream id that is online

**The Code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/swfobject/2.2/swfobject.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        * { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
        body { text-align: center; }
        html, body { height: 100%, width: 100%; }
    </style>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var flashvars = {};
            var params = {
                allowscriptaccess : "always",
                allowfullscreen : "true",
                wmode : "transparent"
            };
            var attributes = {};
            swfobject.embedSWF("http://www.own3d.tv/livestream/34046;autoplay=true", "player", "400", "300", "11.0.0","expressInstall.swf", flashvars, params, attributes);             
        });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="player" style="visibility: hidden;"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```